# Error in corCFA(fun_call = match.call(), ...) : object 'mycor' not found

Tags: r, r-lavaan, reliability

I have an scale of problematic internet use with 5 items rating from 1 to 5. I am trying to get omega coefficient as recommended by [Flora (2020)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/2515245920951747), but I get the following error:

Make example reproducible
`set.seed(1)`

Create example data frame
`df <- as.data.frame(matrix(round(runif(n=5, min=1, max=5), 0), nrow=923, ncol = 5))`

Define the model
`mod_1 <- 'P_INT_USE_1 =~ V1 +  V2 + V3 + V4 + V5'`

Fit the cfa to obtain omega coefficient from semTools:reliability function
`fit_1<- cfa(mod_1, data=df, std.lv=TRUE, ordered=TRUE, estimator='WLSMV')`

Any ideas on how to overcome this, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Other than changing the case of your `data` parameter from `DF` to `df` in your `cfa()` call, your code runs for me (well, it gives plenty of warnings, but I don't get that error).  The only library I loaded was `semTools`, and I ran in a fresh R session

Comment: You are right! Maybe there is another package overlapping? I am using ‘readr’ to load my original database and I get this warning:  "The following object is masked from ‘package:semTools’:clipboard"

    clipboard.

Comment: I used a different package to load my data and it worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: FYI, `semTools::reliability()` is deprecated.  I wrote the `semTools::compRelSEM()` function as a replacement.

Comment: Thanks! I obtained both alpha and omega through this function now. However, in the previous version I could obtaing omega using the model-implied variance of the total scora as the denominator (omega or omega2) and omega using the observed sample variance as the denominator (omega3). Is it still possible to obtain both of them, please?